# Strip all html tags with jquery?

Tags: jquery

How to strip out all html tags in jquery. the function  like strip_tags in PHP

eg: there is some contents as the following:

```
 <div id='test'>This is <b>bold</b> and this <div>is</div> <i>italic</i>.</div>
```

Now i want to change it to `<div id='test'>This is bold and this is italic.</div>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `.text()`:

```
$('#test').text($('#test').text());
```

I used `.text()` twice because using `.html()` to set the contents will cause strings with lesser-than and greater-than signs to be rendered incorrectly:

```
Hello &lt;foo&gt; // Set with .text()
Hello <foo>       // Set with .html()
```

If you used `.html()`, then `<foo>` would become a tag.