# Getting html characters in the ajax success response

Tags: php, jquery

I am Uploading both data and files in one form using Ajax as given answer in the post
[Uploading both data and files in one form using Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899384/uploading-both-data-and-files-in-one-form-using-ajax)

I need to display the response in the alert as shown below

```
file uploaded successfully
Thanks for uploading
```

But i am getting response as `file uploaded successfully<br/>Thanks for uploading`
So, can any one tell me how to get the  response without any html tags..

Comment: Serve the response without the `<br>`s?

Comment: Please provide the exact extract of your code in which the answer is constructed.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10255766/strip-all-html-tags-with-jquery

Comment: Why is your server script sending `<br/>` if you don't want them? If it's sending HTML, you should use `.html()` to display it, not `.text()`.

Comment: just curious, where does your message **file uploaded successfully<br/>Thanks for uploading** comes from? maybe you should trace where you've echoed it an modify it from there.

Comment: the response is coming form another php file as response in the alert@Paw Cabelin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(data).text()` for stripping `<br/>`

Comment: where i have to add the above statement in jquery code,so tell me how to escape html characters in ajax success response

Comment: at `success: function (data) {
            alert($(data).text());
        },` code

Comment: i tried ur code, now i am getting output as 'file uploaded successfullyThanks for uploading' not like this 
'file uploaded successfully
Thanks for uploading'

Comment: @lalith458 you want space betwwen them?? then replace `<br/>` tag with `space`

Comment: not space i need to display that two messages in separate lines

Comment: what is ur actual code for display?? show it again.

Comment: i just posted in the question know,like that i need to display the response..

Comment: I dint get solution till now,tell me how to get the correct response

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29192/discussion-between-lalith458-and-deval-shah)